# What happens if I do not notify Google of the domain change?

Tags: google-search, change-address-tool

If I do not announce the transfer of my site to Google and close the 301 redirect, will the site be introduced as a new site?

By site transfer I mean domain change.

Comment: "**close** the 301 redirect" - Was there a 301 redirect initially?